# Script to send alert mail if disk usage exceeds a percentage

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting, and want to implement a script on my server which will automatically send e-mail alerts if:

- Disk usage exceeds 90%
- Disk usage exceeds 95% (In addition to the previous e-mail)

My filesystem is `abc:/xyz/abc` and my mount is `/pqr`. How can I set this up via scripts?

Comment: You could use `icinga` which would also allow you to monitor a lot more then just the disk usage.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the df command to check the file system usage. As a starting point, you can use the below command:

```
df -h | awk -v val=90 '$1=="/pqr"{x=int($5)>val?1:0;print x}'
```

The above command will print 1 if more than threshold, else print 0. The threshold is set in val.

Note: Please ensure the 5th column of your df output is the use percentage, else use appropriate column.

Comment: @Andy Lester- Here is what i tried
ADMIN="someone@def.com"
ALERT=90
df -k | grep -vE 'abc:/def | tmpfs |cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
do
usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ]; then
mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep" $ADMIN
fi
done

But the output is not as desired.